# Assign random numbers to column B based on column A. All duplicates in A get same random number

Tags: r, random, duplicates, vectorization

I am trying to assign numbers randomly to a column (B) based on the numbers in another column (A). If column A has duplicates, I'd like those duplicates to have the same random number assigned.

```
ColA=c(112,111,004,678,112,262,963) 
RandomNumbers=c(.02, .08,.03,.05, .09,.01,.07)

ColB=c(.09, .02,.01,.03,.09,.08,.05)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like what you want has nothing to do with random numbers: you're looking for a hash function.

Comment: I'm using runif to create the RandomNumbers variable. The above was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to choose the "random numbers"  since your list does not look very random.    Using your list,  you can just assign each "random" number a name based on the value in ColA and refer to that.

```
names(RandomNumbers) = unique(ColA)
ColB = RandomNumbers[as.character(ColA)]
 112  111    4  678  112  262  963 
0.02 0.08 0.03 0.05 0.02 0.09 0.01
```

Comment: I'm using runif to get the random numbers. The above was just to simplify. This definitely works! Thank you so much @G5W

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to skin this cat.  I would create a random number look up table and then left_join the original list with the look up table as follows.  But this is just one possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

Df <- data.frame(ColA =c (112,112,004,678,112,262,963))
LookUpDf <- data.frame(ColA = unique(Df$ColA),
                       randNum = runif(length(unique(Df$ColA))))
left_join(Df, LookUpDf)
```